# Ajax scriptmanager namespaces

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, proxy

Recently I added my Ajax webservice to a namespace (MyCompany.Web.MyService)... The problem is it regenerates the proxy in javascript as MyCompany.Web.MyService.

Is there a way to override the name of the javascript proxy to just MyService? or at least make MyService an alias for MyCompany.Web.MyService in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you [A proxy generator to WebServices for JavaScript and AJAX](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/JavaScriptProxy_01.aspx)